# Dagger 2.11 - A binding with matching key exists in component

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I have a small scenario where I have this following structure where I'm trying to inject fragment manager in baseActivity Fragment but for some reason I'm running out of luck :(

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { AppModule.class,
        ActivityModule.class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class })
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Override
    void inject(App application);

    @Component.Builder interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        AppComponent.Builder application(App application);

        AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

ActivityModule.class

```
@PerActivity
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = BaseActivityModule.class)
abstract BaseActivity baseActivity();
```

BaseActivityModule.class

```
static final String ACTIVITY_FRAGMENT_MANAGER = "ACTIVITY_FRAGMENT_MANAGER";

@PerActivity
@Named(ACTIVITY_FRAGMENT_MANAGER)
@Provides
static FragmentManager activityFragmentManager(BaseActivity activity) {
    return activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
}
```

BaseAcitivity.class

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends DaggerAppCompatActivity {

    @Named(ACTIVITY_FRAGMENT_MANAGER)
    @Inject
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
}
```

So even though i'm providing my fragment manager in BaseActivityModule.class dagger is throwing this following error. I even tried with just Activity instead of BaseActivity as my input parameter in BaseActivityModule. Even then I land up in this same issue. Not sure what exactly I'm screwing up. So any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

```
Error:(17, 8) error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] @javax.inject.Named("ACTIVITY_FRAGMENT_MANAGER") android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
@javax.inject.Named("ACTIVITY_FRAGMENT_MANAGER") android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager is injected at
com.abc.views.base.BaseActivity.fragmentManager
com.abc.views.def.ABCActivity is injected at
dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(arg0)
A binding with matching key exists in component: om.abc.views.base.BaseActivity_BaseActivity.BaseActivitySubcomponent
```

Comment: How / what are you injecting? I'm guessing you're using other activities than a single BaseActivity. You'll have to provide the dependency from their components, the BaseActivity one gets ignored

Answer (score 30, accepted):

"A binding with matching key exists in component" means that you have bound a dependency somewhere in your entire object graph but it cannot be reached from the subcomponent where it needs to be injected.

[image: Sibling component contains the binding that the user wants]

Here is the [javadoc](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/391aeebf4fff0af03bfadb10121455592cbbba6d/java/dagger/internal/codegen/MissingBindingSuggestions.java):

> Utility code that looks for bindings matching a key in all subcomponents in a binding graph so that a user is advised that a binding exists elsewhere when it is not found in the current subgraph. If a binding matching a key exists in a sub- or sibling component, that is often what
> the user actually wants to use.

For instance, assume you have two Activities, `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`. You generate subcomponents with `@ContributesAndroidInjector` and bind `Foo` in the `ActivityA` module but not the `ActivityB` module. If you request injection for `Foo` in `ActivityB` with `@Inject Foo foo` you will get that error message.

Forming subcomponents using `@ContributesAndroidInjector` on a base class like `BaseActivity` is probably not a good approach here. Like in the comment from [David Medenjak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1837367/david-medenjak), the subcomponent for the base class will be ignored and the subcomponent for the concrete class will perform injection on `ABCActivity`.

For now, you can fix your error by binding `FragmentManager` in the subcomponent for `ABCActivity` :

```
@PerActivity
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = BaseActivityModule.class)
abstract ABCActivity ABCActivity();
```

Comment: I see your point. what if i don't make a subcomponent for `BaseActivity` and use it as `@Module(includes = ABCActivityModule.class)` in my `ABCActivityModule.class`. Is it suppose to work ?? 
When i tried it it results me to same error.

Comment: @user3354265 can you try doing a clean/rebuild? If that doesn't work, can you post your `ABCActivityModule`?

Comment: Just did rebuild no change. 
BaseActivity Module is same as above. 

I'm still injecting in baseActivitity but I'm only including BaseActivityModule in my ABCActivityModule which looks like this.
`@Module(includes = BaseActivityModule.class)
 public abstract class ABCActivityModule {
     @PerFragment
     @ContributesAndroidInjector
     abstract ABCFragment abcFragment();
 }`
Also, ABCActivity extends BaseActivity. So my main requirement is I want to use addFragment from my ABCActivity that 's y i want to inject fragmentManager in BaseActivity

Comment: @user3354265 are you sure you are providing the same flavour of `FragmentManager`? Perhaps you can carefully check the import statements. A common mistake is to use `android.Fragment.FragmentManager` in`android.support.v4.FragmentManager` somewhere else

Comment: I have already checked that i'm using support one. I think it doesn't like the injection in baseActivity not completely sure why??

Comment: @user3354265 can you change the signature of your provides method to `activityFragmentManager(Activity activity)` ?

Comment: Since i'm using support one i tried using AppCompatActivity. same result :(

Comment: @user3354265 I don't think you will be able to easily get it to work with the base class. Maybe just live with the duplication for now and in a later stage in your project you can extract a base class

Comment: I really appreciate your help towards this. Right now i'm just using getSupportFragmentManager in base but it'll be nice if i can actually get it work. I made a [public repo](https://github.com/kdani41/Dagger2_11_support) for this scenario. If you ever get a chance please take a look. Thanks a lot I really appreciate your time :)

Comment: @user3354265 I did a pull request for your repo - would you mind accepting the answer (green tick)?