# Dagger: A binding with matching key exists in component

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I am using Dagger 2.16 and was following [this](https://medium.com/@iammert/new-android-injector-with-dagger-2-part-2-4af05fd783d0) article for my dagger implementation. Everything was working fine with this implementation until I had only one Activity(HomeActivity). As soon as I started implementing Dagger in SplashScreenActivity. I started getting this error. Here is some code from my project

**AppComponent.kt**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidInjectionModule::class,
    AppModule::class,
    ActivityBuilder::class,
    ServiceBuilder::class,
    BroadcastRecieverBuilder::class])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<MyApp> {
    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<MyApp>()
}
```

**AppModule.kt**

```
@Module()
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContext(application: MyApp): Context {
        return application
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRestService(retrofit: Retrofit): RestService {
        return retrofit.create(RestService::class.java)
    }
    ...
}
```

**ActivityBuilder.kt**

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [HomeActivityModule::class])
    @PerActivity
    abstract fun bindHomeActivity(): HomeActivity

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [SplashScreenModule::class])
    @PerActivity
    abstract fun bindSplashActivity(): SplashScreenActivity
}
```

**BaseActivity.kt**

```
abstract class BaseActivity<V : BaseView, P : MvpBasePresenter<V>> :
        MvpActivity<V, P>(), BaseView, HasSupportFragmentInjector {
    @Inject
    lateinit var fragmentInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

    @Inject
    lateinit var mPresenter: P

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun createPresenter(): P = mPresenter

    override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment> {
        return fragmentInjector
    }
}
```

I have my own BaseActivity instead of DaggerActivity because I what to inherit from mosby's MvpActivity.

**SplashScreenModule.kt**

```
@Module
abstract class SplashScreenModule {

    @Binds
    @PerActivity
    internal abstract fun splashPresenter(splashPresenter: SplashScreenPresenter): BasePresenter<*>
}
```

**HomeActivityModule.kt**

```
@Module
abstract class HomeActivityModule {

    @Binds
    @PerActivity
    internal abstract fun homePresenter(homePresenter: HomeActivityPresenter): BasePresenter<*>

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [DownloadFragmentModule::class])
    @PerFragment
    internal abstract fun downloadsFragment(): DownloadsFragment
}
```

Now when I build this, I get an error as follows

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment>,javax.inject.Provider<dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment>>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<com.realtime.app.MyApp> {
                ^
  A binding with matching key exists in component: com.realtime.dagger.ActivityBuilder_BindHomeActivity.HomeActivitySubcomponent
      java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment>,javax.inject.Provider<dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment>>> is injected at
          dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector.<init>(injectorFactories)
      dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> is injected at
          com.realtime.core.BaseActivity.fragmentInjector
      com.realtime.splashScreen.SplashScreenActivity is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)
  component path: com.realtime.dagger.AppComponent → com.realtime.dagger.ActivityBuilder_BindSplashActivity.SplashScreenActivitySubcomponent
```

I have gone through other similar que like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47106818/dagger-2-11-a-binding-with-matching-key-exists-in-component) but couldn't relate it to what I am facing. What am I missing?

**Update:** For now I am not inheriting BaseActivity in SplashScreenActivity so that I can avoid injecting `fragmentInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>`. It is working for now as I don't have any fragment in SplashScreenActivity.

Comment: Is this the full error? `java.util.Map,javax.inject.Provider>>` looks cut-off. Could you try with the `AndroidSupportInjectionModule` instead of `AndroidInjectionModule`?

Comment: Yeah you are right. Using Blockqoute, some phrases were getting removed. Fixed that now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Yea, it looks like you're missing `AndroidSupportInjectionModule`, could you try switching it as mentioned above?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak well i'll be damned. `AndroidSupportInjectionModule`  fixed it. I would have never found that out myself. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works for `HomeActivity` because it binds a fragment:

```
@ContributesAndroidInjector
fun downloadsFragment(): DownloadsFragment
```

SplashScreenActivity does not.

---

`AndroidInjection` uses `DispatchingAndroidInjector` to handle runtime injections, which basically contains a `Map` of classes to their component builders. This map needs to be injected like everything else. In the case of HomeActivity the fragment declaration in the module generates a binding for the map, which can then be injected.

Since there is no Fragment on the splash activity Dagger does not know about any bindings, let alone any map. Which is why it complains that it [*cannot be provided*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912080/1837367).

You can read more [here about multibindings](https://google.github.io/dagger/multibindings.html#declaring-multibindings).

To prevent this from happening, you should register [`AndroidInjectionModule`](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/AndroidInjectionModule.java) on your AppComponent, which just contains the declarations for the empty maps.

While it contains the declaration for `android.app.Fragment` it does not for `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, which is where the error comes from.

---

So to fix this specific error you should add [`AndroidSupportInjectionModule`](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/support/AndroidSupportInjectionModule.java) to your component, which also includes the support bindings, providing an empty map when there are no fragments in an activity.

```
@Component(modules = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, /* ... */])
interface AppComponent { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: You really made my day !! I was using AndroidIjection instead of AndroidSupportInjection and getting the same error as the founder of this post. Thank you !